# ImportError: cannot import name 'hex_regex'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, pip, virtualenv

I'm working on adding [django-location-field](https://github.com/caioariede/django-location-field). However when I add the following code

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from location_field.models.spatial import LocationField

address = map_fields.AddressField(max_length=200, blank=True)
location = LocationField(based_fields=['city'], zoom=7, default=Point(1.0, 1.0))
```

the same as it's ReadMe tutorial it throws an error

```
python3 manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7efbe781bd90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    from django.contrib.gis import gdal
  File "/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 41, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.layer import Layer
  File "/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/layer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.feature import Feature
  File "/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/feature.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.geometries import OGRGeometry, OGRGeomType
  File "/home/samuel/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/geometries.py", line 52, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geometry import hex_regex, json_regex, wkt_regex
ImportError: cannot import name 'hex_regex'
```

I've tried checking online for any issue similar to this dealing with this package and haven't found any.

I'm using django 2.1.2 with python 3 on a virtualenv.
Here's the result from pip freeze

```
apsw==3.16.2.post1
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==17.4.0
Automat==0.6.0
Babel==2.6.0
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
CherryPy==8.9.1
click==6.7
cloudinary==1.12.0
colorama==0.3.7
configobj==5.0.6
confusable-homoglyphs==3.1.1
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.1.4
cssselect==1.0.3
cssutils==1.0.2
defer==1.0.6
defusedxml==0.5.0
deluge==1.3.15
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.14
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-background-image==0.0.1
django-bootstrap==0.2.4
django-bootstrap4==0.0.6
django-compressor==2.2
django-decouple==2.1
django-extra-views==0.11.0
django-haystack==2.8.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-live-support==0.1.9
django-mathfilters==0.4.0
django-oscar==1.6.4
django-phonenumber-field==2.0.0
django-registration==2.4.1
django-tables2==1.21.2
django-treebeard==4.3
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.2
dnspython==1.15.0
enum34==1.1.6
factory-boy==2.11.1
Faker==0.9.0
feedparser==5.2.1
funcsigs==1.0.2
gunicorn==19.9.0
gyp==0.1
heroku==0.1.4
html5-parser==0.4.4
html5lib==0.999999999
httplib2==0.9.2
hyperlink==17.3.1
idna==2.7
incremental==16.10.1
ipaddress==1.0.17
keyring==10.6.0
keyrings.alt==3.0
lxml==4.2.1
Markdown==2.6.9
mechanize==0.2.5
mock==2.0.0
msgpack==0.5.6
netifaces==0.10.4
numpy==1.13.3
olefile==0.45.1
PAM==0.4.2
pbr==4.1.1
phonenumbers==8.9.10
phonenumberslite==8.9.10
Pillow==5.2.0
PinguyBuilder-gtk==5.1.post6
psycopg2==2.7.5
psycopg2-binary==2.7.5
purl==1.4
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycairo==1.16.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0.1
pygame===1.9.1release
Pygments==2.2.0
pygobject==3.26.1
pyliblzma==0.5.3
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
pyquery==1.2.9
pyserial==3.4
python-apt==1.6.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
python-debian==0.1.32
python-libtorrent==1.1.5
pytz==2018.5
pyxdg==0.25
PyYAML==3.12
rcssmin==1.0.6
regex==2017.12.12
repoze.lru==0.7
requests==2.19.1
rjsmin==1.0.12
Routes==2.4.1
SecretStorage==2.3.1
service-identity==16.0.0
simplejson==3.16.0
six==1.11.0
SOAPpy==0.12.22
sorl-thumbnail==12.4.1
text-unidecode==1.2
Twisted==17.9.0
ubuntu-cleaner==1.0.4
Unidecode==1.0.22
urllib3==1.23
uTidylib==0.3
variety==0.6.9
virtualenv==16.0.0
webencodings==0.5
WebOb==1.7.3
whitenoise==3.3.1
wstools==0.4.3
wxBanker==1.0.0
wxPython==3.0.2.0
wxPython-common==3.0.2.0
xmltodict==0.11.0
zope.interface==4.3.2
```

Comment: What version of `django`, etc. are you using? Can you share the result of `pip freeze` of your virtual environment?

Comment: I am actually running into this issue rn. That being said your `pip freeze` does not appear to actually be running `Django2`

Comment: I'm getting exact same error with python 3.6 while building a docker image with Django. Docker image builds successfully with Django==2.0.13 but fails with the above error with Django==2.2.10

Answer (score 1):

Yeah so I was running into this issue also. You need to uninstall Django and reinstall it. That or blow away your virtualenv and recreate it. Both cases making sure you're install Django2.

```
pip uninstall -y Django
pip install Django==2.2
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, although it's missing some details.  This error happens if you have multiple django versions installed.  In my case I had 1.11 and 2.2 both installed (one globally and one under my user dir).  I had to remove everything and ensure I only had Django 2.2 installed.